# rowwise flattened outer product in eigen

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I have m by n matrix A, m by k matrix B. I want to obtain m by (nxk) matrix C whose each row is a flattened outer product of rows of A and B. Is there an easy and efficient way to do this? Thanks!

Example:

```
A:
1 2
3 4

B:
 0.5  2
-0.5 -2

C:
0.5   1  2  4
-1.5 -2 -6 -8
```

Comment: This is like a row-wise Kronecker product (I don't think there is an efficient one-line solution for this in Eigen). How large are `m`, `n`, `k`? And generally, are you sure you need to explicitly store `C`? Computing larger data `m x (n*k)` from smaller `m x (n+k)` is often a sign that you are wasting memory and probably computation time.

Comment: `m` is around 10, `n` and `k` could be up to hundreds. This question came up when I was trying to implement some "expansion" of input features, which I will feed into a linear regression. For example, input could be b by f0, which you can think of b as batch size and f0 as input feature dimension. I want to apply transformations to expand the feature dimension: e.g. do pow(0.1), pow(0.5) and pow(1.0), and have an output that's b by f1=f0*3. Thanks!